# Stock checker api in wix

Tags: development-environment, developer-tools, velo

Website is already complete in wix. 
I want whenever someone click at add to cart an external API will be used to check if item is there in stock or not if yes only than it will be added to cart.I just want to know is there any possibility to do this????
Need help new on stack overflow...

Comment: How big is your product list? if its small you can use the Wix built in databases to keep track of your inventory or upload a csv/xls file.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but you will need to custom code the Products Page which is a really big task in itself especially if your product count is more than 1000 and many products have variants.

On the custom coded product page: Whenever someone clicks on the 'Add to Cart' button you should show a loader and in the background make an API call to your endpoint to get the JSON response. Once you have the response analyze the data to determine whether the product should be allowed to add in cart or not.